# Win32 textBox in treeview

Tags: winapi, treeview

I want to add `textbox` in `treeview` as child of one of the parent node. Is it possible> If yes how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The native TreeView control isn't going to be helpful at all to make this work.  Programming one yourself is a tricky proposition.  It is however a very popular UI gadget.  Any component vendor sells one, invariably called "TreeList".

You'll have to do some shopping if you want to use such a component from unmanaged C/C++.  An ActiveX version of such a control is as close as you can get.  Most component vendors have however put that in their legacy bag.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Can u please suggest any library?

Comment: I always avoid buying advice, I can't warrant code I didn't write.  Especially when I have no idea what kind of class libraries you use or what kind of programming you prefer.  Find the component vendor by googling "TreeList", check out their support forums to see how responsive they are.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements, you may be able to use the built-in label editing features of the Win32 tree view.  See [`TVM_EDITLABEL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773562(VS.85).aspx).

To make an item act like an edit control, you could send this message yourself when the item is clicked.  You could also use [owner-draw techniques](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761817(VS.85).aspx) to make the item look more like an edit control when it isn't in label-editing mode.